# How to obtain bounding box of transformed text(java)?

Tags: java, user-interface, swing, text, bounding-box

Currently I have a text object that I need to determine its bounds. I used to use the graphics object to obtain the font metrics of the text I am trying to draw, but since I added functionality to rotating the object(and possibly more) I need a better way to get the bounds of this object. I have looked multiple places and nothing has really worked for me as of yet. Here is my most current attempt:

```
//This is the bounding box edges 0: left, 1: right 2: top 3: bottom  
int toReturn[] = new int[4];
//this.transform is the AffineTransform for the text Object(currently only
//rotated)
FontRenderContext frc = new FontRenderContext(this.transform,true,false);
TextLayout tl = new TextLayout(this.typedText,this.font,frc);
Rectangle2D bb = tl.getBounds();
toReturn[0] = (int)(bb.getX());
toReturn[1] = (int)(bb.getX()+bb.getWidth());
toReturn[2] = (int)(bb.getY());
toReturn[3] = (int)(bb.getY()+bb.getHeight());
```

Is this the proper way to get the bounding box for transformed text?

Comment: Reformatted code; please revert if incorrect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the `AffineTransform` supplied to [`FontRenderContext`](http://download-llnw.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/font/FontRenderContext.html) "is used to scale typographical points to pixels in this FontRenderContext." You should be able to use [`createTransformedShape()`](http://download-llnw.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/geom/AffineTransform.html#createTransformedShape%28java.awt.Shape%29) on the boundary to get the result you want.

Comment: Thanks for the reply (and the edit), im not sure quite how to format my code again in this reply so i apologize, but if I understand you properly is this what you mean:

Shape shape = transform.createTransformedShape("some Shape");

The only question I would have now is what shape would be provided to that method?

tl.getBounds()?

Comment: @heater: Yes, `tl.getBounds()` or `font.getStringBounds()`; it's very convenient for `contains()` testing. If you need the transformed coordinates themselves, use one of the `transform()` methods of `AffineTRansform`. BTW, use back-ticks for in-line code; indent four for code listings.

Comment: thanks for the quick response and info for in-line code, this seems to work how I want it to :)

Comment: @heater: Glad to help. You can also click on any "edited _n_ _units_ ago" link to peek at interesting effects.